# MySql Entity Framework error with OrderBy and Take

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I've done some reading and this query should work.  I just want to order by descending, take the top 15 records, and select them into objects.  Removing OrderByDescending works, but without the order, of course.  Removing Take works, but without a limit.  Is there any reason I'm missing that this query isn't working?

```
var query = context.blogs.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDate).Take(15).Select(x => new Blog
    {
      id = x.id,
      Title = x.Title,
      Content = x.Content,
      Summary = x.Summary,
      CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate,
      CreatedDateText = x.CreatedDate.ToString(),
      Image = x.Image,
      Author = x.Author,
      BlogCategories = x.blogcategories.OrderBy(y => y.category.Name).Select(y => new BlogCategory
      {
        id = y.id,
        Category = new Category
        {
          id = y.category.id,
          Name = y.category.Name
        }
      }).ToList()
    }).ToList()`
```

The error that shows up during this query is `MySqlException: Unknown column 'Project1.C1' in 'field list'`

The query that gets output is

```sql
SELECT
`Project2`.`id`, 
`Project2`.`Title`, 
`Project2`.`Content`, 
`Project2`.`Summary`, 
`Project2`.`CreatedDate`, 
`Project2`.`C1`, 
`Project2`.`Image`, 
`Project2`.`Author`, 
`Project2`.`C2`, 
`Project2`.`id1`, 
`Project2`.`CategoryId`, 
`Project2`.`Name`
FROM (SELECT
`Limit1`.`id`, 
`Limit1`.`Title`, 
`Limit1`.`Content`, 
`Limit1`.`CreatedDate`, 
`Limit1`.`Image`, 
`Limit1`.`Author`, 
`Limit1`.`Summary`, 
`Limit1`.`C1`, 
`Join1`.`id` AS `id1`, 
`Join1`.`CategoryId`, 
`Join1`.`Name`, 
CASE WHEN (`Join1`.`id` IS NOT NULL) THEN (1)  ELSE (NULL) END AS `C2`
FROM (SELECT
`Project1`.`id`, 
`Project1`.`Title`, 
`Project1`.`Content`, 
`Project1`.`CreatedDate`, 
`Project1`.`Image`, 
`Project1`.`Author`, 
`Project1`.`Summary`, 
`Project1`.`C1`
FROM `blog` AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Project1`.`CreatedDate` ASC LIMIT 15) AS `Limit1` LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
`Extent2`.`id`, 
`Extent2`.`CategoryId`, 
`Extent2`.`BlogId`, 
`Extent3`.`id` AS `ID1`, 
`Extent3`.`Name`
FROM `blogcategories` AS `Extent2` INNER JOIN `categories` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent2`.`CategoryId` = `Extent3`.`id`) AS `Join1` ON `Limit1`.`id` = `Join1`.`BlogId`) AS `Project2`
 ORDER BY 
`Project2`.`CreatedDate` ASC, 
`Project2`.`id` ASC, 
`Project2`.`C2` ASC, 
`Project2`.`Name` ASC
```

Anyone know what is wrong with this query?

Blog model:

```
public class Blog
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
public string Summary { get; set; }
public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
public string CreatedDateText { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }
public string Author { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<BlogCategory> BlogCategories { get; set; }
}
```

BlogCategory model:

```
public class BlogCategory
{
public int id { get; set; }
public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Category model:

```
public class Category
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

blog entity:

```
public partial class blog
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public blog()
        {
            this.blogcategories = new HashSet<blogcategory>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<blogcategory> blogcategories { get; set; }
    }
```

blogcategory entity:

```
public partial class blogcategory
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int BlogId { get; set; }

        public virtual blog blog { get; set; }
        public virtual category category { get; set; }
    }
```

category entity:

```
public partial class category
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public category()
        {
            this.blogcategories = new HashSet<blogcategory>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<blogcategory> blogcategories { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you add `blog` and `category` models to the question?

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi I've updated the question with all the models

Comment: good job, I'll check it.

Comment: let simplify the generated query and then see what happens. after `Take(15)` call `ToList()` and tell me does it work or no?!

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi Yeah, that works.  Weird. I suppose worst case scenario I could select into the objects afterwards, but it's weird that the select works fine with one or the other. Any ideas why that may be happening?

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi turns out CreatedDateText = x.CreatedDate.ToString() was the line that was breaking it.  Removing that fixed it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Very good, but you know it's not really necessary to persist `CreationDateText` in the database. after fetching data you could map your model to a `DTO` or `ViewModel` which have `CreationDateText` property.

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi that's what I'm doing here. Blog is the model, blog is the entity. I'm selecting the datetime from CreatedDate and when mapping to the model I'm calling ToString on the date for a property called CreatedDateText

Comment: Hmm, I got it now. their naming is not very good `blog` & `Blog` !!

Comment: I agree, renaming the model was on my todo list once I got the base functionality working.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's my pleasure